# Picture or text below (and part of) the number of an enumerated item

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem

It's my problem, I don't know how to do picture or text, bottom in enumerate number. Therefore I couldn't write code, even. Bottom in enumerates have one picture or/and two picture or/and mini text.

I didn't find duplicate another question. So, does anyone know how to fix it?

Changed Citation: *Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 4th ed - C. Alexander, M. Sadiku (McGraw-Hill, 2009) page 444*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use stacks to place an image or text underneath the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item first

\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\stackunder{\theenumi.}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=.02]{example-image}}] second

\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\stackunder{\theenumi.}{%
  \tiny Boo!}] third

\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\stackunder{\theenumi.}{%
  \Shortstack{\includegraphics[scale=.02]{example-image}\\
              \includegraphics[scale=.02]{example-image-B}}}] fourth

\item fifth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the text following the enumerate label is more than one line, you probably would want to `\smash` the label to avoid it messing with the line spacing of the item.  For example, if item 4 in the above MWE were multi-line, it might be written as such, with the smashed label:

```
\item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\smash{\stackunder{\theenumi.}{%
  \Shortstack{\includegraphics[scale=.02]{example-image}\\
              \includegraphics[scale=.02]{example-image-B}}}}] fourth
item in a long list of items.  The number four follows the 
number three and occurs prior to the number five.  If you look
closely, you will see that the smashed label allows even spacing
in the item.
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. It's working for me. But If **second** item text was long, first and second lines separate. I'll work to this solve.

Comment: @Özgür  See my revision, with note at the end.

Comment: perfect working. Thanks for solve my problem exactly.

Comment: I want to host you if you arrived İzmir in Turkey.