# Placing image below the bullet points

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Bezrobocie}

\begin{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]   
\item <1-> ddddd
\item <2-> dddddd 
\end{itemize}

\includegraphics[scale=0.3, center, trim=1.75cm 11cm 0.5cm 11cm]{ddddd}



\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Having the following frame in latex beamer i want to position includepgraphics object bellow the bullet points furthermore i want this image to appear as the last thing on slide. How to do this, because i am not able to find reasonable option?

Comment: Possible duplicate, if you mean to place an image below a particular, or below each bullet point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199481/picture-or-text-below-and-part-of-the-number-of-an-enumerated-item

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide working examples, not just fragments of code

Comment: i mean bellow all bullet points, i have a set of bullet points and i want an image below

Comment: When I compile a generic equivalent of your document, the image **is** below the `\item` markings.  Might the bounding box of your image be awry?

Comment: that is not what i seen after compliation

Comment: maybe the trim option is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to uncover the image at last, you should use the uncover option :

```
\uncover<2>{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{image.pdf}}
```

the number is the number of the slide.

To put the image at the right side and under the bullet, you can use a very small line where you put a unbreakable space with the ~ sign. One example is :

```
\begin{itemize}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]   
    \item <1-> ddddd
    \item <2-> dddddd 
    \item
    {\fontsize{0.1}{0.1}\selectfont ~}\vspace{-5pt}{\fontsize{0.1}{0.1}\selectfont ~}
    \uncover<3>{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{images}}
\end{itemize}
```

If it's only below,

```
\begin{itemize}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]   
    \item <1-> ddddd
    \item <2-> dddddd 
\end{itemize}
\uncover<3>{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{images}}
```

should work fine.

I'm not sure that I well understood your question. Let me know.